# Inner / Left outer Join with conditional column matching

Tags: sql-server, join

I need some help with left outer join/inner join with condition such as below;

```
select a.val1,a.val2,b.val1,b.val2,..
from tableA a 
inner join tableB b 
on (if a.val1<>0 then a.val1=b.val1
  and if a.val2<>0 then a.val2=b.val2
  and if a.val3<>0 then a.val3=b.val3
  and if a.val4<>0 then a.val4=b.val4)
where a.description='ABC'
```

I wanted to match certain columns only based on the condition if value is not zero null

Any help would be appreciated.
I have tried CASE WHEN and so forth without any success.
Please provide me with correct syntax to match the above example, as I am not an expert on this.
Thanks.

### ZEE

Thanks for your reply Hogan, I know your example was good, but it didnt work out for me, due to 
my lack of explanation on the scenario.

Please see the sample data here;

```
MainTable                               
MakeID|Make---|ModelID|Model|ColorID|Color---|SizeID|Size|Mat
1     |Polo   | 1     | LT  |  1    |Black   | 1    | S  |Cot
1     |Polo   | 1     | LT  |  1    |Black   | 2    | M  |Pol
1     |Polo   | 2     | XT  |  2    |Red     | 3    | S  |Pol
2     |Gap    | 3     | NK  |  3    |Black   | 4    | S  |PolCot
2     |Gap    | 4     | LK  |  4    |Red     | 5    | M  |Wool
3     |Arrow  | 5     | MM  |  5    |Black   | 6    | L  |Wool
3     |Arrow  | 5     | MM  |  6    |White   | 7    | XL |Pol
3     |Arrow  | 6     | LM  |  7    |Black   | 8    | S  |Cot
4     |Zig    | 7     | HG  |  7    |Green   | 9    | S  |PolCot
4     |Zig    | 7     | HG  |  7    |Green   | 10   | M  |Wool
```

```
MapTable                        
MapID|ItemID|MakeMatch|ModelMatch|ColorMatch|SizeMatch|Material
1    |ABC   | 1       | 1        | 1        | 1       |Cot
2    |ABC   | 1       | 2        | 0        | 0       |Pol
3    |ABC   | 3       | 6        | 0        | 0       |Wool
4    |ABC   | 4       | 7        | 7        | 0       |PolCot
5    |XY    | ..      | ..       | ..       | ..      |..
6    |XY    | ..      | ..       | ..       | ..      |..
7    |XY    | ..      | ..       | ..       | ..      |..
```

Results I expect to pull:
one of either below;

```
MapID|Make--|Model|Color--|Size|Mat
1    |Polo  |LT   |Black  |S   |Cot
2    |Polo  |XT   |null   |null|Pol
3    |Arrow |LM   |null   |null|Wool
4    |Zig   |HG   |Green  |null|PolCot
```

OR below;

```
MapID|Concat-Field
1    |Polo-LT-Black-S-Cot
2    |Polo-XT--Pol
3    |Arrow-LM--Wool
4    |Zig-HG-Green--PolCot
```

Using maptable, I am required to pull the records consist of itemid='ABC' and get the matching values from MainTable for each the iDs represented like MakeMatch,ModelMatch,ColorMatch,SizeMatch. It always fill the value in this order MakeMatch,ModelMatch,ColorMatch,SizeMatch . MakeMatch always will be filled, But Other Fields can be zero. Eg. If ColorMatch is Zero, its parents MakeMatch,ModelMatch always will be filled. But SizeMatch will be zero as well if ColorMatch is zero.

So I've tried different ways to pull using Inner join and Left outer join, but to no avail.
Could you please kindly advise me what is the best way to pull the expected results shown here.

Note: Having trouble posting due to Containe unformatted code.. Trying section by section..

Thank you Hogan,
Appreciate your reply. The code you provided, produced the results I wanted,
except that I had to include 
`select distinct`

```
SELECT distinct M.MapID, Model.Make, Model.Model, Color.Color, Size.Size, M.Material
FROM MapTable AS M
JOIN (SELECT MakeID, Make 
  FROM MainTable 
  GROUP BY MakeID, Make) AS Make ON M.MakeMatch = Make.MakeID
LEFT JOIN MainTable Model ON M.MakeMatch = Model.MakeID AND M.ModelMatch = Model.ModelID
LEFT JOIN MainTable Color ON M.MakeMatch = Color.MakeID AND M.ColorMatch = Color.ColorID
LEFT JOIN MainTable Size ON M.MakeMatch = Size.MakeID AND M.SizeMatch = Size.SizeID
where M.ItemID = 'ABC'
```

However, In one scenario, it was slightly different results though. 
When I have added one more record to mapTable as follows

```
7    |ABC   | 2       | 0        | 0        | 0       |Wool
```

After adding this record, the results was like below;

```
MapID|Make--|Model|Color--|Size|Mat
1    |Polo  |LT   |Black  |S   |Cot
2    |Polo  |XT   |null   |null|Pol
3    |Arrow |LM   |null   |null|Wool
4    |Zig   |HG   |Green  |null|PolCot
7    |null  |null |null   |null|Wool
```

The last 7th record did not pull the Make.

Just for your information, I have tried the following codes which gives the correct results. But I know this is not an efficient way.
If you could look at the code below and suggest a better coding would be greatly appreciated.

```
select Maptable.mapid ,concat(
(select top 1 make from MainTable where MainTable.makeid=MapTable.MakeMatch)+'--->', 
(select top 1 model from MainTable where MainTable.modelid=maptable.ModelMatch)+'--->', 
(select top 1 size from MainTable where MainTable.SizeID=MapTable.SizeMatch)+'--->',
(select top 1 Color from MainTable where MainTable.ColorID=MapTable.ColorMatch),
maptable.material) as Selection
from maptable  where maptable.itemid = 'ABC'
```

this one produced the results below, which I needed.

```
    MapID | Detail
    1      Polo--->LT--->S--->Black-->Cot
    2      Polo--->XT--->Pol
    3      Arrow--->LM--->Wool
    4      Zig--->HG--->Black-->PolCot
    7      Gap--->Wool
```

Once again, I would appreciate if you could provide me with better efficient coding for the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now that I see your example data I can give you the correct SQL:

```
SELECT M.MapID,  Make.Make, Model.Model, Color.Color, Size.Size, M.Material
FROM MapTable AS M
JOIN (SELECT MakeID, Make 
      FROM MainTable 
      GROUP BY MakeID, Make) AS Make ON M.MakeMatch = Make.MakeID
LEFT JOIN MainTable Model ON M.MakeMatch = Model.MakeID AND M.ModelMatch = Model.ModelID
LEFT JOIN MainTable Color ON M.MakeMatch = Color.MakeID AND M.ColorMatch = Color.ColorID
LEFT JOIN MainTable Size ON M.MakeMatch = Size.MakeID AND M.SizeMatch = Size.SizeID
```

No case statements needed -- just simple left joins.

---

**original answer**

Use a case statement like this:

```
select a.val1,a.val2,b.val1,b.val2,..
from tableA a 
inner join tableB b 
on  CASE WHEN ISNULL(a.val1,0)=0 then b.val1 ELSE a.val1 END =b.val1
and CASE WHEN ISNULL(a.val2,0)=0 then b.val2 ELSE a.val2 END =b.val2
and CASE WHEN ISNULL(a.val3,0)=0 then b.val3 ELSE a.val3 END =b.val3
and CASE WHEN ISNULL(a.val4,0)=0 then b.val4 ELSE a.val4 END =b.val4
and (ISNULL(a.val1,0) <> 0 OR ISNULL(a.val2,0) <> 0 
  OR ISNULL(a.val3,0) <> 0 OR ISNULL(a.val4,0) <>0)
where a.description='ABC'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But my situation is bit more complex.. and wanted to match the inner join on columns..

Comment: @Zee - see edit.  This is exactly the logic in your question.  So how does this not solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But my situation is bit more complex.. and wanted to match the inner join on column...I will edit my post with some sample data from table.

Comment: This is matching the inner join on the column.

Comment: Please see Edit. Thank you. Appreciated.

Comment: The select had a typo, it should be : `SELECT M.MapID,  Make.Make, Model.Model, Color.Color, Size.Size, M.Material` -- cf http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f2cd3/5

Comment: Thanks a lot, This is what I exactly needed. Please forgive the repeated post due to my lack of knowledge in this area. You are the BEST.

Comment: YW.  Check out sqlfiddle -- if you have another question putting an example on there can really help people on SO answer your question quickly

Comment: Thanks, never knew this online utility. I can use this in the future.